# mysql select count(*) with where scan full table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an innodb table with 100M records like this:

```
id    name   pid cid createdAt
int   char   int int timestamp
```

id is PK, and pid is indexed: `key`

the most often query is `select count(*) from table1 where pid='pid'`

my question is does this query do a full table scanning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(*)` is very rarely what you want.

The `count` function counts rows that are not null, so `count(name)` counts records where the `name` field is not null for example. If the field being counted is not indexed then this results in a full table scan.

In the case of `count(*)` the database counts records that have at least one non null field, ie it excludes records where all of the fields are null. This might be what you want, but most people incorrectly use this form when they want to just count all of the records regardless of their content.

The most efficient way of counting all of the records without database specific syntax is `count(1)`. This works because the value `1` is not null for every record, and does not require any data to be read from the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what the query does, then look at the "explain" plan.

If you want to speed the query in question, then create an index on `table1(pid)`.

The query should scan the index rather than the table.